# how to open other app activity from myapp?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an app that opens other apps with intents and it works perfectly, but now I need to open a specific activity and I don't know if it's even possible.

already installed both app and I am not able to open specific activity from my app.

```
btnCallActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("com.rayvatapps.flatplan", "com.rayvatapps.flatplan.LoginActivity");
                intent.putExtra("WEBVIEW_URL", "https://google.com/");
                startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "oops...app is not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rayvatapps.flatmaps">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Other App"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.rayvatapps.flatplan.app.LoginActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i am getting following error

```
Error: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.rayvatapps.flatplan.app.LoginActivity }

E/Error: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.rayvatapps.flatplan/.LoginActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{4310b06 9701:com.rayvatapps.appdemotest/u0a384} (pid=9701, uid=10384) not exported from uid 10378
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post the manifest of the app you are trying to start (the second one)

Comment: please check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package and class names do not match. Based on the manifest of the app you want to start, you need to change this:

```
intent.setClassName("com.rayvatapps.flatplan", "com.rayvatapps.flatplan.LoginActivity");
```

into this:

```
intent.setClassName("com.rayvatapps.flatmaps", "com.rayvatapps.flatmaps.LoginActivity");
```

You also don't need the `<intent-filter>` on the `Activity` in the app you are trying to start, as you are using an explicit `Intent` to start it. If you remove the `<intent-filter>` make sure that you keep the `android:exported="true"` for the `Activity`, otherwise you won't be able to launch it from another application.

Comment: sir is it possible to open non exported activity on a rooted device? if yes then how to secure our app?

Comment: On a rooted device you can do anything you want. Including changing the "exported" status of any `Activity`. There is no way to secure anything on a rooted device.

Answer (score 2):

In **Manifest.xml of Second Apps Activity** add **Intent Filter** -> **android.intent.category.DEFAULT**

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.ActivityName" 
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.demo.any_name" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then from your app

```
    Intent launch = new Intent("com.demo.any_name");
    startActivity(launch);
```

Comment: have you added intent-filter in manifest inside activity tag of your other app?

Comment: see updated answer..  add **exported = true** in activity tag

Comment: 'android:exported="true"` is not necessary if there is an `<intent-filter>`, as the presence of `<intent-filter>` automatically sets `android:exported="true"`